# Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am getting below error:

Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

My pom.xml file is:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.BBMSearchApp</groupId>
  <artifactId>adder</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>adder Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
 </parent>
  
   <dependencies>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
   <version>1.7.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
 -->
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId> 
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId> 
        </dependency> -->
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.json</groupId>
   <artifactId>json</artifactId>
   <version>20141113</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>  
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>  
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>  
  </dependency>
        
  <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency>
         <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
         <version>2.1.5</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
         <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
         <version>2.10.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- <dependency>
   <groupId>org.neo4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.1</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5</version>
  </dependency> -->
  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
   <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
   <version>1.9.30</version>
  </dependency>
  
   </dependencies>
   
   <build>
     <finalName>adder</finalName>
 
  <plugins>
         <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
             <configuration>
                 <source>1.8</source>
                 <target>1.8</target>
             </configuration>
         </plugin>

  </plugins>
 </build>
 <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>


 
</project>
```

And debug logs are:

```html
Apache Maven 3.2.5 (12a6b3acb947671f09b81f49094c53f426d8cea1; 2014-12-14T22:59:23+05:30)
Maven home: C:\Dev\apache-maven-withCustomReposiory\apache-maven-3.2.5
Java version: 1.8.0_11, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 8.1", version: "6.3", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from C:\Dev\apache-maven-withCustomReposiory\apache-maven-3.2.5\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from C:\Dev\apache-maven-withCustomReposiory\apache-maven-3.2.5\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo
[DEBUG] Using manager EnhancedLocalRepositoryManager with priority 10.0 for C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project com.BBMSearchApp:adder:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging war from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-bom:4.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Extension realms for project org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:pom:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: (none)
[DEBUG] Looking up lifecyle mappings for packaging pom from ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]
[DEBUG] Resolving plugin prefix spring-boot from [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:133)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:150)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.loadPlugin(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:81)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:138)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolveFromProject(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:125)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:85)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:260)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:85)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:294)
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:129)
 ... 24 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:jar:1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT
 at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:434)
 ... 28 more
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote request for org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo)
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using transporter WagonTransporter with priority -1.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[DEBUG] Using connector BasicRepositoryConnector with priority 0.0 for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml (13 KB at 4.8 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo\org\apache\maven\plugins\resolver-status.properties
[INFO] Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml (20 KB at 6.9 KB/sec)
[DEBUG] Writing tracking file C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo\org\codehaus\mojo\resolver-status.properties
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.313 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-05-02T23:05:55+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/208M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\DK\.m2Custom\repo), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
 at org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.internal.DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginPrefixResolver.java:93)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.findPluginForPrefix(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:260)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoDescriptorCreator.getMojoDescriptor(MojoDescriptorCreator.java:220)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:103)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.calculateTaskSegments(DefaultLifecycleTaskSegmentCalculator.java:83)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:85)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
 at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
 at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
 at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
 at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: The dependency you have requested `spring-boot-maven-plugin` does simply not exist in this version

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add  the version part,it works for me

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The OP was specifically trying to use spring 1.3 so using 1.2.7 is not really a solution.

Answer (score 8):

You must add following excerpt to `pom.xml` for compiling with **SNAPSHOTS** and **MILESTONES**:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
         </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this pom.xml for the resolution. What @acoder2013 said is perfectly correct. :)

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>Springboot</groupId>
<artifactId>com.spring.services</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>repository.spring.release</id>
        <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>repository.spring.milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
```