# How to solve problem with importing spring application with Maven?

Tags: spring, maven, intellij-idea

I have java api that I'm trying to import in Intellij using Maven and this is what I'm getting:

> Cannot resolve plugin org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:

This is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>sample</groupId>
<artifactId>sample-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>Parent </description>

<modules>
    <module>sample-repository-mongo</module>
    <module>sample-service</module>
    <module>sample-webservice</module>
</modules>

<prerequisites>
    <maven>3</maven>
</prerequisites>

<properties>
    <framework.version>0.0.0</framework.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Module dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.everis.cordis.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample-webservice</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.everis.cordis.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample-service</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>eu.everis.cordis.sample</groupId>
            <artifactId>sample-repository-mongo</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Unit Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>


<dependencies>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <!-- <finalName>${warname}</finalName> -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <outputDirectory>.</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

So far, the only thread about similar problem I could find is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005460/plugin-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-maven-plugin1-3-0-build-snapshot-or)
I've tried solution from there with latest version and it didnt help unfortunately.

I have java 8 for the project structure and I've tried with Maven 3.6.2 and 3.6.1 also, because some time ago I was able to import it with Maven 3.6.1 on a different laptop.

I've double checked java and maven environmental variables and I know that they are okay. Also I've tried running `mvn clean install, mvn install, mvn package, mvn validate` and any other command I could find but the problem remains the same.

Comment: Can you try `mvn -U clean install` - to force dependency update ?

Comment: The pom that you are showing is your parent pom, right? Then why do you have a build section and not a pluginManagement section like you have for the dependenceis?

Comment: And this pom has no parent artifact. Usually a Spring boot project has the artifact `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent, and not as regular dependency.

Comment: I tried to run `mvn -U clean install`, but it didnt change, it tells me an error about encoding and still shows a bunch of errors. Yes. This is a parent pom for 3 modules and I dont really know Maven, I know that I imported this project before and it worked and I cant figure out what is the problem now. Should the parent pom be structured differently?

Comment: Can you add the exact error messages ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Spring boot project, so the pom [must have a parent](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-first-application.html). Simply add these lines at the top of your pom.xml:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</parent>
```

This parent will take care of versions of dependencies.

Comment: I had to change the version from 2.1.8 to 2.0.3 but it worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I was having version **2.3.4** which was causing issue in my IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1 (Ultimate Edition). Changing it back to **2.3.2** resolved the issue for me. Now I am having below configuration :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```