# Maven Plugin not found in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I have a new error in my project that is in the pom.xml file. How can I fix it?

The error below shown in IntelliJ idea:

```
Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
```

Comment: Please check this similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30005460/plugin-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-maven-plugin1-3-0-build-snapshot-or

Comment: Can you build from command line? Do you have proxies?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

From the Preferences in Intelli J, navigate to "Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven", check the "Use plugin registry", and click "OK".

Then "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart" to reload Intelli J. The error will go away automatically.

Comment: In Windows, it is File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment

Comment: this solution didn't work for me, but it gave me a hint. Finally, I upgraded to version 2.5.5, then the issue was resolved. And then I removed the ver 2.5.5 statement, still worked. Then I realised, actually, you should do something, include but not limit to upgrade version/invalidate & restart/re-install, to force intellij refreshing cache...

Comment: If you are someone like me who keep 10 workspaces open at the same time, this will blow away your next 15 minutes for a reasonably size project. Get ready for some patience if you try this!

Comment: Awesome, worked for me. I also selected
- Clear file system cache and Local History
- Ask  before  downloading new shared indexes

Then clicked the "Invalidate and restart" button.

Answer (score 78):

Add following code

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${parent.version}</version>
    </plugin>
```

and then click on the icon as shown in screenshot, to load Maven changes in pom.xml file

[image]

Comment: in spring boot v2.4.0: [WARNING] The expression ${parent.version} is deprecated. Please use ${project.parent.version} instead.

Comment: This solution worked for me too with changes suggested by @Yaqoob. Bundle of thanks !

Answer (score 24):

I had the same problem. This summer Intellij suddenly started throwing this error but build went through. I just had to specify version of plugin and it stopped throwing this error.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: How did you find the version information?

Comment: @Bigeyes Trial and error I guess. I couldn't find information about it on jetbrains forums or stack overflow.

Comment: @Bigeyes It is supposed to be the spring boot version used in the file. You can use `${parent.version}` as well, which refers to the same thing.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem using IntelliJ version 2020.2.4. The solution was to edit the pom.xml file and specify the version of the Spring-Boot Maven plugin, with the following syntax:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </plugin>
```

This Intelli-J release does not recognize the "RELEASE" keyword after the version number, as suggested in the previous answer.

Comment: Please note that this answer only applies to Spring Boot versions 2.4.0+ due to [changes in the versioning scheme](https://spring.io/blog/2020/04/30/updates-to-spring-versions#project-module-version-changes) which dropped the usage of "RELEASE". Versions 2.3.x and below are still published in the form of `x.x.x.RELEASE`.

Comment: Better would be <version>${parent.version}</version>

Comment: The expression `${parent.version}` is deprecated. Please use `${project.parent.version}` instead.

Comment: This answer plus changing to ${project.parent.version} instead of ${parent.version} worked for me.  Thank you @JohnGood

Answer (score 7):

What worked for me after long tries is updating the indices of the remote maven repository:

**Settings** > **Build, Execution, Deployment** > **Build Tools** > **Maven** > **Repositories**.

Then select the remote repository and then update.

This must work.

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when you are using a milestone or snapshot release. It will be resolved after adding appropriate `pluginRepository` elements.

You can read more about it here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started

```
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

PS: Above answers worked because they explicitly mentioned a different version, which is not milestone or snapshot. IMO that's not the ideal solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to update your IDE. It will fix the issue permanently. As, Apparently there was some bug in the IDE which got fixed in build No: **Build #IU-211.7142.45, built on April 30, 2021.**

Answer (score 0):

By default my configured snapshot project inherited from the spring-boot-starter-parent and set the parent. I added version number and it now as follows:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.4</version>
</parent>
```

As docs suggests:
"You should need to specify only the Spring Boot version number on this dependency. If you import additional starters, you can safely omit the version number. "
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 0):

To add to anyone coming across this problem, I am on WSL and my project was in the linux part of wsl (i.e, outside of the mnt folder). What DID fix the problem for me (after countrless tries to update the remote repository, invalidate caches, `mvn clean compile` and other similar things) was the following :

to cut one random dependency from my `pom.xml` file, click on the icon shown on [Vivek Singh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68791579/7059810) and afterwards repaste that dependency and reclick on the icon.

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

After so many unsuccessful tries I just clicked on the Event Log on the bottom right of the IDE then found out that my pom file  had become a non managed then chose to Add as a maven project and then the  maven window reappeared

Comment: Where is the "Add as a Maven project" option exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Just started type version from scratch and IDE suggested
[mopversion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oBuS.png)

Answer (score 0):

go to File > invalidate cahes ...
[image]