# Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I'm facing an error in my **pom.xml** file given below:

```
Plugin 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:' not found
```

Below is my pom.xml :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.che</groupId>
    <artifactId>stu</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>stu</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: You should probably be more specific about your error. Is it given by your IDE like Intelllij IDEA? Or it occurs when you `mvn compile`?

Comment: I have the somewhat the same issue. IntelliJ's maven editor marks it red. All maven processes run without error (with my setup).

Comment: I have updated my answer for Intellij IDE as well if someone is looking for.

Comment: This solution worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27168770/1180993

Answer (score 380):

I fixed the problem adding the version of the plugin in the pom.xml, which is the same of spring boot's version. (and it's working since spring boot 2.2 until 2.7.X)

So you just have to configure your pom like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: No !! You don't have to add this version tag. Spring boot projects can automatically handle plugin version

Comment: It can. But somehow is not working. That's why this post exists

Comment: i have got this problem in IDEA 2021.2. But i have'nt the problem in earliest versions. Interesting

Comment: I added `<version>${project.parent.version}</version>` and then removed and it is now working with IntelliJ.

Comment: Yes, this is what it was said above.
But nice that worked for you =)

Comment: @AnishB. You are right, but this seem to be the only option if you don't want to keep looking at the ugly red color in IntelliJ. For other maven plugins you may use variables, but for `spring-boot-maven-plugin` you cannot! In `spring-boot-dependencies-2.5.5.pom`, all the plugins in `<pluginManagement>` have variables for their version, such as `<version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>`, but for some cryptic reason `spring-boot-maven-plugin` has hardcoded `<version>2.5.5</version>`.

Comment: Good @HonzaZidek, so just keep this code as suggested as in this topic for now =)

Comment: this solution worked for me in idea 2022.1

Comment: this removed the error but normally the spring-boot-maven-plugin version doesn't have to be specified when using spring-boot-starter-parent   
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/

Answer (score 63):

i fixed the problem adding a version of the plugin in the pom.xml

```xml
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
```

Comment: You should not write the version like this. Instead of it, you should refer the version number.

Comment: In my case was a fix:
<version>2.4.5</version>

Comment: No, don't hard-code there the version number directly, use rather the parameter like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824948/2886891

Comment: why not write the version like this? why not hard-code?

Answer (score 34):

The **pom.xml** is correct. It seems that there is a network issue. The plugin was not downloaded due to that.

**Steps to solve the issue :**

- Check for network issue. You need to have a strong internet connection to download all the dependencies and plugins using maven. **Otherwise, you will face issue to build maven project for sure.**
- For **eclipse/STS** :

  1. **Right click on the project** >> **Run As** >> **Maven clean** (this will clean the project by deleting the **target** folder).

     Example :

[image]

3. **Right click on the project** >> **Run As** >> **Maven install** (this will download all dependencies and generate **target** folder).

Example :

[image]

4. If problem still persists, then last option is to force refresh of the project. **Right click on the project** >> **Maven** >> **Update Project**.

[image]

5. **Update Maven Project** Window will be come.

[image]

Note: Enable the option **Force update of Snapshot/Releases** (look in above screenshot). By default, this option is not enabled. Click on ok. It will start updating.

---

- For **Intellij IDE** :

1. Open the Maven tab present on the right tab and check for spring-boot-maven-plugin.

[image]

2. If the plugin was not downloaded, then click on **clean** maven lifecycle and it delete the folders that were generated by maven.

[image]

3. Then, click on **install** maven lifecycle and it will download all the dependencies and generate all the folders from scratch required for the project.

[image]

4. Last step is to force update of the project. You need to click on the **Generate Sources and Update Folders for All Projects** option.

[image]

Note : Go the **Preference** -> **Build, Execution and Deployment** -> **Build Tools** -> **Maven** -> **Enable "Always update Snapshots" option present** -> Click on **Apply** and **Ok**. This option helps sometimes.

---

- For Without any IDE :

1. Download maven from [here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and extract it.
2. Set maven location on the environment variable so that it can run from anywhere.
3. Open CMD/Terminal and then do `mvn clean install` inside the project.

---

**Update for viewers:** `<version>` tag is not mandatory tag to be there for spring-boot projects because **pom.xml** created by spring for spring-boot can handle the version of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

- Better create a proper spring-boot project from https://start.spring.io

Updated **pom.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>dev.che</groupId>
    <artifactId>stu</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>stu</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Edit :**

If above steps are not solving your issue, then you can go for the workaround solution by explicitly providing the parent spring boot version in the `plugin` for `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (not a recommended solution):

```
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>${parent.version}</version> 
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: '''mvn clean install''' worked for me! I had to download Maven too from [Here](https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and I also followed [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--Iv5vBIHjI)

Comment: It did not work for me. Unfortunately (I am **not** happy with the solution!) only https://stackoverflow.com/a/66824948/2886891 worked.

Comment: @HonzaZidek It should work. I gave this solution with testing only. I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: @HonzaZidek Actually, Intellij is good when it comes to gradle projects but not with maven projects. I use maven projects with eclipse for most of time. Anyways, Intellij can handle maven projects but you need to know proper settings to use maven effectively.

Comment: @AnishB If I run `mvn clean install` and Maven is happy without warnings, I expect the same result from IntelliJ IDEA. `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is in spring-boot `<pluginManagement>`, so the version should not be required. However, IDEA is unhappy. This should work out of the box, not "know proper settings" should be needed :( So I **had** to go for the workaround solution with `${project.parent.version}`, even if I don't like it. And BTW, `${parent.version}` produces another warning...

Comment: `<version>${parent.version}</version>` is work for me

Comment: This should be marked as answer. Much more complete and still working.

Comment: Worked, thank you!. If you have mvn wrapper, you can do    ./mvnw clean install

Answer (score 15):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67000013/3052880) worked for me:

> From the Preferences in Intelli J, navigate to "Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven", check the "Use plugin registry", and click "OK".
>
> Then "File > Invalidate Caches / Restart" to reload Intelli J. The error will go away automatically.

I just followed these steps in IntelliJ IDEA:

Click **File** from menu and then click **Invalidate Caches / Restart**.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30157451)

Comment: I've included the essential parts of the answer by providing link and by quoting. Thanks for informing.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't work for me.

Answer (score 8):

I fixed this problem by adding version:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 7):

I encountered this issue in January 2022 when the version changed to 2.6.3. I lowered the version of the project to 2.6.2 as well but was unsuccessful. However adding the following line `<version>${project.parent.version}</version>` plugins solves the issue regardless of the version. The snippet is given below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 4):

If solution suggested by Anish B doesn't work and you are using intellij, try deleting the .idea and *.iml file from the project directory and open the pom.xml file with intellij. This should fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I faced this error while learning Springboot in 2023, I easily fix it by adding the following line at the spring-boot-starter-web dependency:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

it works definetely :
add this `<version>${project.parent.version}</version>`
in `Pom.xml`
like this :

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
```

or another solution is :
add `<version>2.4.3</version>` in `pom.xml`

Answer (score 3):

Simply add version of the spring-boot-starter-parent in the plugin section
i.e

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
```

Change into

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
</plugin>
```

check out [here](https://exerror.com/plugin-org-springframework-bootspring-boot-maven-plugin-not-found/) for more details

Answer (score 3):

This could be due to network issue which lead to partial download of dependencies and plugins. For me below step worked in IntelliJIDEA:

Close the project from editor: File -> Close Project

Then reopen the project.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is if you have `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in a sub-module which parent has `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent.

So, the module with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` is a 'grandchild' of `spring-boot-starter-parent`.

If that's the case, since you can't reference AFAIK the grandparent, you need to manually add its `version`.

I am open to recommendations, so that I don't need to manually set the `version` in such a configuration.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue today 22 Jan 2022 using spring boot 2.6.3 from Intelij IDE and was able to resolve it by changing from 2.6.3 back to 2.6.2 .As of the time of writing I was getting this error

> Cannot resolve plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.2.2

```
        <parent>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
           <version>2.6.2</version>  <!-- change 2.6.3 to 2.6.2-->
           <relativePath/>
        </parent>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried a lot of the solutions here but only this worked for me:

I changed the Maven wrapper to "Bundled" in the "Maven home path" configuration. You can find this at the menu: Preferences > Build, execution, development > build tools > maven

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your pom.xml file, go to the plugins section and then add this line below artifactId.

```
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
```

Your code should look like this:

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
```

Then load maven changes and it should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add in "Remote Jar Repositories"

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/
```

And add in `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

then add in `*.java`

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved my package with controllers into the same package where IntroApplication is, for noobs like me it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking on my pom.xml -> Maven -> Reload Project did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your dependencies are not loaded into your project if you declared them at a later point.

**For IntelliJ IDEA**

Right click on your project > **Maven** > **Reload Project**

This should fix the error.

Comment: Error keeps showing up

Answer (score 0):

just use the last version of `spring-boot-maven-plugin`

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin

or use same version of

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.7.1</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

**For intellij**

- right click on the pom.xml
- locate maven and select rebuild rebuild
  project.

Answer (score 0):

In  my case it was just inserting the Spring Boot parent version and the error disappeared
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.0.1
stayed like this
org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-maven-plugin
3.0.1

Answer (score 0):

For me this was nothing to do with versions or any IDE settings, it was simply calling spring-boot:repackage on its own.

It has to be called with package, so:

```
mvn package spring-boot:repackage
```

Has to be done and not:

```
mvn spring-boot:repackage
```

I'm assuming that this changes values in the reactor and the second call has a different method to use. When I look at the method that was failing it is now deprecated:

```
Create a new Packager instance.
Deprecated
since 2.3.10 for removal in 2.5 in favor of Packager(File) and setLayoutFactory(LayoutFactory)
Params:
source – the source archive file to package layoutFactory – the layout factory to use or null
```

And so probably calling it on its own will result in this method call and thus erroring. The "new" chained method is obviously behaving differently and therefore works.

Answer (score 0):

Issue with --release flag occurs when the java version of the project doesn't match with the environment, solution is to check and update the environment variables for JAVA_HOME,MAVEN_HOME,PATH with set command.

Moreover make sure you add properties for java version and maven release version as below:

```
<properties>
  <java.version>18</java.version>
  <maven.compiler.release>18</maven.compiler.release>
</properties>
```

After making change do not forget to clean the project, update the project and then mvn install.

Answer (score 0):

I have an edge solution, in IntelliJ IDEA. When my mouse hovers over the `<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>`, I get the version and use it as

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.2.0</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

in intellij 2022 i faced this problem; and solve it by adding a line:

```
<version>${project.parent.version}</version>
```

in my "pom.xml":

```
<project>
  ...
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing SDK default to the version of Java used helped me. (For intellij idea).

**Project Structure -> Project -> Language level -> If it is SDK default change to your Java version**

And then try to sync.

Answer (score -1):

**Quick solution**

I tried all the solutions above and realized that the dependencies were not being downloaded.
That's when I knew it was a network issue. My network was
strong so I knew it had too be the firewall. I added
intellij IDE to my list of exceptions and it worked like charm.