# Plugin 'com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.2.1' not found Intellij Idea

Tags: maven, vaadin, pom.xml, intellij-plugin

In
**POM.xml**
I have:

```
`<artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>`
`<version>23.2.1</version>`
```

It doesn't recognise it
and says `Plugin 'com.vaadin:vaadin-maven-plugin:23.2.1' not found` for both these lines of code

Comment: Have you tried if the plugin actually works by building/running the tasks with the maven CLI? Or is this specific to intellij?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63468269/maven-plugin-not-found-in-intellij-ide

Answer (score 0):

The plugin itself can be found in Maven Central with that version number: https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-maven-plugin/23.2.1/maven-plugin

So the problem could either be that your `pluginRepositories` doesn't contain something like follows:

```
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    <!-- ... -->
```

...or that your IntelliJ Idea doesn't have access to Maven Central. Maybe you're using a private repository like Artifactory, for example.

Make sure you've clicked "Reload All Maven Projects" from the Maven tab, too.